# How to open uml sequence diagram in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

The uml sequence diagram was drawed in visual studio 2015, and it can still be opened in 2015.  But double click the diagram file in 2017, the visual studio shows me xml instead of draw the diagram.
[image]
[image]

So, what is the right way to open diagram in visual studio 2017?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check it out: [UML designers have been removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/what-s-new-for-design-in-visual-studio#uml-designers-have-been-removed). You may stay in VS 2015 to continue using this feature.

Comment: astonishing 'new' feature……

Comment: I like to know about MS thinking method